# Proving $d\varphi^{\mu_1} \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_2}... \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_k}$ is basis for space of $k$-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms, hamel-basis

Let $X$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with a local chart $(U,\varphi)$. Taking the wedge product of the chart induced covariant basis $\{d\varphi^\mu\}$:
\begin{align}
\{d\varphi^{\mu_1} \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_2}... \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_k}:1\leq \mu_1 \leq ... \leq \mu_k \leq n\}
\end{align}
gives an basis for the space of $k$-forms $\Omega^k(X)$.

I have already proven linear independence and now have to prove that these $k$-forms span $\Omega^k(X)$. Let $\omega \in \Omega^k(X)$ and define:
\begin{align}
\omega_{\mu_1...\mu_n} = \omega(\textbf{e}_{\mu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\mu_k})
\end{align}
where $\{\textbf{e}_{\mu}\}$ is the chart-induced contravariant basis. We claim that
\begin{equation}
        \omega = \omega_{\mu_1...\mu_k}d\varphi^{\mu_1} \wedge ... \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_k}
\end{equation}
To see why this holds, note that since $\omega$ is multi-linear we just need to look at the action of our candidate basis on $(\textbf{e}_{\nu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\nu_k})$:
\begin{equation}
   (d\varphi^{\mu_1} \wedge ... \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_k})(\textbf{e}_{\nu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\nu_k})
\end{equation}
Due to the duality of $\textbf{e}_{\nu_j}$ and $d\varphi^{\mu_i}$, the contributing terms will be delta functions $\delta^{\mu_i}_{\nu_j}$. We then have that:
\begin{align}
     (d\varphi^{\mu_1} \wedge ... \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_k})(\textbf{e}_{\nu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\nu_k})&=\sum_{\pi \in \text{S}_{k}} \text{sgn}(\pi) (d\varphi^{\mu_1} \otimes...\otimes d\varphi^{\mu_k})(\textbf{e}_{\pi(\nu_1)},...,\textbf{e}_{\pi(\nu_k)})\\
     &=\sum_{\pi \in \text{S}_{k}} \text{sgn}(\pi) \delta^{\mu_1}_{\pi(\nu_1)}... \delta^{\mu_k}_{\pi(\nu_k)}
\end{align}
implying that
\begin{align}
    \omega_{\mu_1...\mu_k} (d\varphi^{\mu_1} \wedge ... \wedge d\varphi^{\mu_k})(\textbf{e}_{\nu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\nu_k})&=\sum_{\pi \in \text{S}_{k}} \text{sgn}(\pi) \omega_{\mu_1...\mu_k} \delta^{\mu_1}_{\pi(\nu_1)}... \delta^{\mu_k}_{\pi(\nu_k)}\\
     &=\sum_{\pi \in \text{S}_{k}} \text{sgn}(\pi) \omega_{\pi(\nu_1)...\pi(\nu_k)} = k!\omega(\textbf{e}_{\nu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\nu_k})
\end{align}
where $\text{sgn}(\pi) \omega_{\pi(\nu_1)...\pi(\nu_k)}=\omega(\textbf{e}_{\nu_1},...,\textbf{e}_{\nu_k})$ by anti-symmetry.
However, I should not have this $k!$ factor in my result, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Fix the order of indices, that would clear it up.

Comment: @Berci The order of which indices?

Comment: We can assume $\mu_1<\mu_2<\dots$ and $\eta_1<\eta_2<\dots$.

Comment: So the terms in the sum with $\mu$ restricted gives $1/k!$ of the terms in the sum with $\mu$ unrestricted?

Comment: That's right, I think I got it! For a given list of $\mu_1...\mu_k$ the unrestricted sum gives $k!$ terms, but only one of these terms will appear in the restricted sum, giving the $\frac{1}{k!}$ when contracting the basis with $\omega_{\mu_1...\mu_k}$!

Comment: You still have an error. You need $\mu_1<\mu_2$, etc.

Comment: Yes that's where the $\frac{1}{k!}$ comes from right?